# PDFBox. Java: How to print only one page of PDF instead of full document?

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I want to print specific page of pdf file. In example I have pdf with 4 pages, and I want to print third page. I am using Apache PDFBox lib. I tryied to remove my other pages except that one which I want to print, but it now prints all other pages except that which I want to be printed... any help?

There is my code of function I wrote:

```
void printPDFS(String fileName, int i) throws PrinterException, IOException{
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.getPrintService();          
   // String test = "\\\\192.168.5.232\\failai\\BENDRAS\\DHL\\test2.pdf";
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setPrintService(printJob.getPrintService());
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);

    for(int j=1;j<=doc.getNumberOfPages();j++){
        if(i!=j)
        {
            doc.removePage(j);                
        }
     }
   doc.silentPrint(job);
}
```

I've added this line to code:  `System.out.println(doc.getPageMap());`

Console gives me: `{13,0=4, 1,0=2, 7,0=3, 27,0=1}`
 what does it mean?

Comment: What you printed just means that page 4 is object 4 in generation 0, page 2 is object 1 in generation 0 ...; Those are pdf internal things that you normally don't need to worry about (i.e. it's ids of pdf objects; If you open the document as text file you should should be a pages dictionary with a entry `/Kids [27 0 R 1 0 R 7 0 R 13 0 R]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work since you don't take into account that removing pages also changes the indices of the pages at higher indices and decreases the number of pages. Also page indices are 0-based. Remove the pages like this and it should work:

```
i = Math.max(-1, Math.min(i, doc.getNumberOfPages()));

// remove all pages with indices higher than i
for (int j = doc.getNumberOfPages()-1; j > i; j--) {
    doc.removePage(j);
}

// remove all pages with indices lower than i
for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    doc.removePage(j);
}
```

or alternatively a bit closer to your implementation:

```
for(int j=doc.getNumberOfPages()-1; j >= 0; j--){
    if(i!=j)
    {
        doc.removePage(j);                
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, still not printing. now i gave  value for i "1" and got printed third (3/4) page. instead of first page.

Comment: @Rokas: I've just tested it (again) and both versions print the **second** page as expected, if I pass 1 as `i`, which is the expected behaviour (0-based indices, remember, if you want to pass 1-based indices, just substract 1 at the begining of the method). There must be something else wrong with your code/pdf that you aren't telling us. Do you e.g. different page labels and forgot to mention that? Could you upload the pdf somewhere. I can't help you, if i can't reproduce the problem. BTW: Which version of pdfbox do you use?

Comment: @so what i should do if i want to print 4/4 or 1/2?